# VSCode terminal send same sequence like in iterm

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, iterm, zsh-completion

I am using VSCode integrated terminal together with [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) and [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions). Everything is working as expected except for `autosuggest-execute` command.

I am looking for a way to send `'^[auto'` sequence to VSCode terminal, none of my attempts according to [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-via-a-keybinding) worked so far.

In [Iterm2](https://iterm2.com/), I am successfully able to send sequence like this:

[image]

### ZSH config

```sh
# .zshrc
bindkey '^[auto' autosuggest-execute
```

### Unsuccessful attempts

```json
  {
    "key": "cmd+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u001b^[auto"
    }
  }
```

Note: Works fine out of the box on Ubuntu 20.04, but not on MacOS Catalina (10.15.7 (19H15))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at last

```json
{
  "key": "cmd+e",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "\u001bauto"
  }
}
```